# direção do colisor de rodas no novo gerenciamento de entrada

Tags: c#, unity3d

Estou tentando usar o novo sistema de entrada de unidade 3D para o movimento do meu carro, mais especificamente o ângulo de direção.

quando eu uso Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") minha roda vai suavemente de 0 a 30 e conforme eu pressiono as teclas.

quando eu uso context.ReadValue() salta de 0 a 30 com um clique e retorna a 0 quando liberado sem ser suave.

Não consigo fazer a roda girar no ângulo de acordo com a pressão da tecla e voltar suavemente como no sistema antigo, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
Inputmanage input;
public float currentangle = 0f;
public float angle = 30f;

public void Onmovement(InputAction.CallbackContext context) {

    currentangle = angle * context.ReadValue<float>();
    wheels[0].steerAngle = currentangle;
    wheels[1].steerAngle = currentangle;


}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pô, legal, uma pergunta de Unity3D. Mas traduz a pergunta, please.

Comment: desculpe não vi que já estava no stack pt

Answer (score 0):

Rafael, você pode definir 2 variáveis para fazer a gradação de movimento.

```
private float step = 0.2f; // 0.2 para 5 passos de giro
private float turnStep = 0f;
```

como o evento deve ser chamado várias vezes, podemos fazer a adição à variável turn para definir currentangle.

```
turnStep += step;
currentangle = angle * context.ReadValue<float>() * turnStep;
```